# how to restrict on check multiple checkboxes in jquery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried Following code but not working so please suggest any other method using only jquery.

```js
$("#Checkboxes4 :checkbox").change(function() {
   if($('#Checkboxes4').length > 1){
  $('#Checkboxes4').prop('checked',false);
  $(this).prop('checked',true);
 }
});
```

```html
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Checkboxes">Spices</label>               
<div class="col-md-10 columns">                    
  <label class="checkbox-inline" ><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" id="Checkboxes4" value="1+">1+ Kg</label>             
  <label class="checkbox-inline" ><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" id="Checkboxes4" value="5+">5+ Kg</label>      
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" id="Checkboxes4" value="10+">10+ Kg</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: 'not working'? be more specific

Comment: Say clearly what you want

Comment: If they have the same name (with no brackets like: name='item[]') you can select just one (if I`m not misstaken)

Comment: can you post desired output?

Comment: do you want user to check only one checkbox?

Comment: If you want to select only one checkbox then why not you use radio button rather than this

Comment: @Dnyan Post your html too. it will help others. Also i think something wrong with selector part here. `$(Checkboxes1).length > 1`.

Comment: @Niranjan I want to check any one of them from that three checkboxes.

Comment: @madforstrength I have posted html code plz chk.

Comment: @Dnyan, then you should use radio buttons, not check boxes

Comment: if you want to allow only checkbox to be checked then no need of this . you must use radioButton.

Comment: @InsaneSkulll I want  to use only checkbox.

Comment: @Dnyan: My answer used with checkboxes, you could check it

Comment: @MrNeo yes i have checked

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps radio buttons would serve you better?

Radio buttons are designed for the purpose of having only one radio button in a group checked at any one time, thus fulfilling "restrict on check multiple checkboxes".

This is a better solution than using checkboxes because you don't need to use any javascript nor Jquery to enforce this rule.

Example:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

Demo: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio

Answer (score 1):

Things to be noticed:

1. In this case you should use `radios` with same name group instead.
2. Never use same ids for multiple elements. Every element should have it's unique ID. When same ids happend to be on a page then only first element will get the event to be registered.
3. When it comes to event binding then you can use class names instead because class names always returns a collection.
4. In your case you can change the ID to class and you can use the snippet below.

---

```js
$('.Checkboxes4').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('label').siblings('label').find(':checkbox').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Checkboxes">Spices</label>
<div class="col-md-10 columns">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" class="Checkboxes4" value="1+">1+ Kg</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" class="Checkboxes4" value="5+">5+ Kg</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" class="Checkboxes4" value="10+">10+ Kg</label>
</div>
```

I have changed the attribute `id` to `class="Checkboxes4"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
$('#Checkboxes1').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).siblings(':checked').length > 1) {
   this.checked = false;
}
});
```

Also refer this: [Disable checkboxes when 6 are checked -- multiple forms on page with checkbox groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032693/disable-checkboxes-when-6-are-checked-multiple-forms-on-page-with-checkbox-gr)

Answer (score 0):

First one, you should not set all `input` with the same `id`. Replace `id` by `class`

And following code is the solution with `checkboxes`. Hope this help ^^

```js
$(".a").change(function() {
    $('.a').prop("checked",false);
    $(this).prop("checked",true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Checkboxes">Spices</label>               
<div class="col-md-10 columns">                    
  <label class="checkbox-inline" ><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" class ="a" value="1+">1+ Kg</label>             
  <label class="checkbox-inline" ><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" class ="a" value="5+">5+ Kg</label>      
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" class ="a" value="10+">10+ Kg</label> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML multiple elements with same ID is not allowed..

You need to:

1. Set the listener in the document/body ready event
2. Change the ID to CLASS on the checkboxes
3. Attach the event to checkbox with selected classes.

Here's the working code:

```
 $("body").ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox.Checkboxes4").change(function() {
       if($('.Checkboxes4').length > 1){
            $('.Checkboxes4').prop('checked',false);
            $(this).prop('checked',true);
        }
    });

 });

<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Checkboxes">Spices</label>               
<div class="col-md-10 columns">                    
  <label class="checkbox-inline" ><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" class="Checkboxes4" value="1+">1+ Kg</label>             
  <label class="checkbox-inline" ><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" class="Checkboxes4" value="5+">5+ Kg</label>      
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes4[]" class="Checkboxes4" value="10+">10+ Kg</label> 
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rh6ca5f2/)

Comment: This is the best answer for what i am looking. But its not working for me. I have <input type="checkbox" class="checktablesearch" > and var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox.checktablesearch'); in javascript isnt working. Any idea?